# log file before using rm command

Tags: 14.04

I am using `rm -rf` command to delete data from the folder.

Before deleting I want to know the file name and size that has been deleted from that folder and update in a log file. So that I can know which files are deleted from that folder.

I am using ubuntu 14.04. Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 2):

By using the -v argument you can see (log) everything that is being deleted.
For more, like file size, you need to create a script that parses each directory and file, log the info you want and then delete them.

```
temp (directory) 
 |- 1 (directory)
    |- 2  (directory)
       |-- 3.ge (file)



user@laptop:~$ rm -rfv temp
removed 'temp/1/2/3.ge'
removed directory 'temp/1/2'
removed directory 'temp/1'
removed directory 'temp'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know wich files where deleted you can use the `-v` option with `rm`, like P. Iakovakis already explained.

If you want to simulate the deletion process and get a list which files are going to be deleted before executing the `rm` command you can use `ls -shR` with the delete parameter from `rm`:

Folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

List files before deletion:

```
$ ls -shR folder-to-delete
folder-to-delete:
total 20K
4.0K folder  4.0K test  4.0K test1  4.0K test2  4.0K test3

folder-to-delete/folder:
total 8.0K
4.0K test  4.0K test2
```

Delete files and list them afterwards:

```
$ rm -rfv folder-to-delete
removed 'folder-to-delete/test'
removed 'folder-to-delete/folder/test'
removed 'folder-to-delete/folder/test2'
removed directory 'folder-to-delete/folder'
removed 'folder-to-delete/test2'
removed 'folder-to-delete/test1'
removed 'folder-to-delete/test3'
removed directory 'folder-to-delete'
```

Maybe you want to add the `-l` option to `ls` to get a list representation and more information of the files:

```
$ ls -shRl folder-to-delete      
folder-to-delete:
total 20K
4.0K drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar  5 19:15 folder
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    5 Mar  5 19:15 test
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6 Mar  5 19:15 test1
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6 Mar  5 19:15 test2
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    6 Mar  5 19:15 test3

folder-to-delete/folder:
total 8.0K
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2 Mar  5 19:15 test
4.0K -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4 Mar  5 19:15 test2
```